# Google photos displays pixelated images

Tags: photos, google

Today I noticed that pictures (screenshots, pictures, etc) in my phone (LG F60) are displayed awfully. I use google photo. Until yesterday everything was fine but today i noticed that everything in google photos looks pixelated, like in low quality/ resolution.

Also... I uploaded a screenshot (which looks pixelated on google photos) to imgur, and it looks perfect, the same with every picture I see in the browser, if I download a picture I see it blurry in google photos.

Maybe due to a google+ update?? (Yesterday morning updated to a new version)

Thanks!